Is there a simple way to generate a non-uniformly divided interval according to an arbitrary division function?
I often encounter the need to non-uniformly divide an interval.
For example, in the code below, I already have a uniformly divided interval teven with [t0, t1] and a step size of dt.
Now I want to re-divide this interval according to the division function, ndivFunc,  to obtain a new non-uniformly divided interval tuneven.
I've tried to write a naive code, but it feels too clumsy.
Is there a more direct and simpler way to do this?
Thanks :)
Remove["Global`*"] // Quiet;
t0 = 2;
t1 = 9;
dt = 0.5;

teven = Range[t0, t1, dt]
ndivMax = 10;
ndivMin = 2;
ndivFunc[t_] := 
 Rescale[ndivMax  Cos[2  Pi  1/(t1 - t0) (t - t0)], {-ndivMax, 
   ndivMax}, {ndivMin, ndivMax}]

i = 1;
Subdivide[teven[[i]], teven[[i + 1]], 
  Ceiling@ndivFunc@((teven[[i]] + teven[[i + 1]])/2)];
tunveven = 
 Table[Subdivide[teven[[i]], teven[[i + 1]], 
     Ceiling@ndivFunc@((teven[[i]] + teven[[i + 1]])/2)], {i, 
     Length@teven - 1}] // Flatten // Union

Show[Plot[ndivFunc[t], {t, t0, t1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Deviding Function"}],
 ListPlot[{teven, ndivFunc /@ teven}\[Transpose], 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.01]}, PlotLegends -> {"even"}],
 ListPlot[{tunveven, ndivFunc /@ tunveven}\[Transpose], 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.005]}, PlotLegends -> {"uneven"}]
 ]




To explain the idea, we first do the opposite of what you want. We get a high density of points where ndivFunc is small and low density where ndivFunc is high, we integrate ndivFunc. This gives a function that has a low slope where ndivFunc is low and a large slopw where ndivFunc is large. We apply this new function  to the range {t0,t1} and rescale the result to {t0,t1}:
integ = Function[t, Evaluate[Integrate[ndivFunc[t], t]]];
Plot[integ[x], {x, t0, t1}]
pts = integ /@ Range[t0, t1, dt] // Chop;
pts = Rescale[#, MinMax[pts], {t0, t1}] & /@ pts;
Plot[ndivFunc[t], {t, t0, t1}, 
 Epilog -> Point[Transpose[{pts, ndivFunc /@ pts}]]]



We now have a method to draw a high density of points where ndivFunc is small and a high density where ndivFunc is large. To adapt this to your problem, we linearly transform ndivFunc too reverse high and low, apply it to the range {t0,t1} and rescale the result to {t0,t1};
ndivFunc1[t_] = 10 - ndivFunc[t];
Plot[ndivFunc1[t], {t, t0, t1}]
integ = Function[t, Evaluate[Integrate[ndivFunc1[t], t]]];
Plot[integ[t], {t, t0, t1}]
pts = integ /@ Range[t0, t1, dt] // Chop;
pts = Rescale[#, MinMax[pts], {t0, t1}] & /@ pts;
Plot[ndivFunc[t], {t, t0, t1}, 
 Epilog -> Point[Transpose[{pts, ndivFunc /@ pts}]]]





Wow, that's a very novel approach. Let me think it over a bit more. Thank you!
